# ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText() returning incorrect result when using an expression with casting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this example code within Razor:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => ((VisitGozo.Modules.Data.Events.EventSpecificFieldsData)x.Event.DataObject.SpecificFields).LinkedTourismProduct)`

As you can see, the expression includes casting.  The TextBoxFor makes use of the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText()` method which converts an expression into text for Model Binding.

In the above example, due to casting, the returned field name is just `LinkedTourismProduct` and not `Event.DataObject.SpecificFields.LinkedTourismProduct`.  If there wasn't any casting, this would have returned the full name correctly.

Hence during model binding, it does not bind to the correct property because the property of the Model is `Event.DataObject.SpecificFields.LinkedTourismProduct` and not `LinkedTourismProduct` only.

Any idea why this is happening and is there any other solution/workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal behavior. Only simple expressions (property access and indexer access) are supported by the strongly typed helpers. Casting is not.

The correct way to do this is to have a property on your view model of the correct type:

```
public EventSpecificFieldsData EventSpecificFields { get; set; }
```

and then bind your textbox to it without any casts:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Event.DataObject.EventSpecificFields.LinkedTourismProduct)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Darin, I thought about that as a workaround so it should be fine like that :)